# Convert a 2D velocity field from feet to meters

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following array which is a velocity field in ft/s

```
vel = np.load('smaart/sigsbee2a_migvel.npy')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.imshow(vel, cmap='plasma', aspect=.8)
plt.colorbar(shrink=.5)
plt.title('Modelo Sigsbee 2A (Vp [ft/s])')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I convert this array from ft/s to m/s?

Comment: `vel *= 0.3048` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes! I was missing some steps, that's why this doesn't work at first!